# MYSQL/PHP: Newbie with INSERT INTO

Tags: php

guys
I have the following problem. I've made a database called "dsaidovsite" and SQL table inside it called "General Settings", there I've added ID, and PageTopTitle collumns. In the collumn ID,PageTopTitle is already added a row 0,DSPixels Design .I wanted to do the following: I open the ACP, insert the website title, and a PHP script delete the current row, and insert new with ID 0 again (because php should know which row exactly to remove, that why I use ID to identify the row) and the new PageTopTitle value. Here is the PHP I tried to make:

```
$qry = "DELETE FROM General Settings WHERE id = 0"
$qry = "INSERT INTO `dsaidovsite`.`GeneralSettings`(`ID`, `PageTopTitle`) VALUES('0','$PageTopTitle')";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

It is giving me error `unexpected T_VARIABLE` on:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO `dsaidovsite`.`GeneralSettings`(`ID`, `PageTopTitle`) VALUES('0','$PageTopTitle')";`
```

I think that it is from the `0`, and I don't know how to make it add an exact value into the ID column. I hope you got my point and I'll very happy if you help me with this.

Kind Regards,
Denis Saidov

Comment: As you are new to this, I'd suggest you learning PDO instead. mysql_* functions outdated and will be phased out in near future.

Comment: you need `;` after `$qry = "DELETE FROM General Settings WHERE id = 0"`. I highly suggest reading up on the basics of PHP and looking into what the error messages mean.

Comment: What **exactly** is the **full** error message you get?

Comment: Not sure where the close votes are coming from, I learned a few things from this post. Maybe the title could be more general but I don't think this one is too localized.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
$qry = "DELETE FROM General Settings WHERE id = 0";
mysql_query($qry); //first delete
$qry = "INSERT INTO `dsaidovsite`.`GeneralSettings`(`ID`, `PageTopTitle`)     VALUES('0','$PageTopTitle')";
$result = mysql_query($qry); //then add
```

You missed this ; at the end of the delete ;)

PS: You should go for mysqli or PDO...mysql extension is deprecated

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this down.

First off `unexpected T_VARIABLE` is PHP telling you it ran into a Variable when it wasn't expecting to. Taking this into consideration, it told you what line so we look around there.

```
             $qry = "DELETE FROM General Settings WHERE id = 0"
error line-> $qry...
```

Looking at the line the error provides, you see that there is a variable and what comes before it is another line. At the end of the line we notice no `;`. Done. That problem is fixed.

As for your thought that `0` may be doing it. PHP doesn't care what you're doing in your MySQL command other than to evaluate the string then pass on to MySQL. Your command is good since you used double quotes, `$PageTopTitle` will be evaluated.

Further comments:

You only run `mysql_query` once and that is after the second setting of `$qry` so the `DELETE` command will not be executed.